# How to update specific character positions in an Oracle table field?

Tags: php, mysql, regex, oracle

I have a 14-digit numeric field in my table. I want to update all the numbers like this pattern:

> 50108899772727  Becomes  5010889977*27*27  where the * position will be filled with 0(zero). And the total digit becomes 16.

Please share some ideas how can I achieve my goal.

Comment: Is this an Oracle database or not ?

Comment: yes.. this is an Oracle database. but I am performing this test on a test database.. using mysql..

Comment: Then what is the Oracle tag used for? I also provided an answer thinking it to be a question related to Oracle SQL. But you have accepted an answer which has nothing to do with Oracle SQL

Comment: Good question indeed. Note "Oracle" is the last tag .. But in addition, any update will fail if the column is really limited to 14 digits. I first thought this was the question, or part of the question: how to change a column ? Don't know if you can with the other tag-related methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(?=\d{4}$)|(?=\d{2}$)
```

Try this.Replace by `*`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vD5iH9/34

```
$re = "/(?=\\d{4}$)|(?=\\d{2}$)/m";
$str = "50108899772727";
$subst = "*";

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

way without regex

```
$str=50108899772727;
$arr = str_split($str, 2);
$arr[count($arr)-2].="0";
$arr[count($arr)-3].="0";
$str=implode("",$arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have a 14 Digit numeric field

since you have a **numeric** field, you must use **to_char** explicitly to do any string manipulations. And then use **to_number** to convert it back to **number**.

Using simple **SUBSTR** will be faster than **REGEXP**.

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS
  2    ( SELECT 50108899772727 num FROM dual
  3    )
  4  SELECT to_number( SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(num), 1, 10)
  5    ||'0'
  6    || SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(num), 11, 2)
  7    ||'0'
  8    || SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(num), 13) ) num
  9  FROM DATA
 10  /

             NUM
----------------
5010889977027027

SQL>
```

You could use the same to **UPDATE** the table.

**Edit** Adding the predicate to the query to filter unnecessary updates.

```
UPDATE table_name
 SET column_name = to_number( SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(column_name), 1, 10)
  ||'0'
  || SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(column_name), 11, 2)
  ||'0'
  || SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(column_name), 13) )
   FROM TABLE
  WHERE LENGTH(column_name) = 14
/
```

Comment: You should add a WHERE clause, to be able to let the system see the difference between the manipulated records, and the new/unhandled records (if any). Besides that, I would agree, but it must be noted you can use mathematical functions to do the same. This would require no conversions, but the functions are more complex.

Comment: OP said - *I want to update all the numbers* Else, I agree nobody wants to update all the rows, especially in a production system.

Comment: You didn't understand. It's not about updating part of the records only, it's about protecting the rows that have been updated already. You don't know if new records may be included at some point, or for whatever reason it may be re-run. Actually, there's 2 reasons to add such a Where clause : 1. it prevents already updated records to be updated again (often resulting in chaos, if you do update the same), 2. You don't charge the database with updates that are not needed (as they are updated already - this is especially in cases where updates may be technically repeatable).

Comment: well in that case, `where length(column) = 14` should suffice. But only OP knows what is more required. The main requirement was the update logic.

Comment: Only OP knows what is required right, but nothing prevents from giving a better solution, as part of a service. In the OP it says "numbers like these patterns". You just assume all records to be like that ? That's quite an assumption. If you ever see an Update without a Where clause, it's almost always a bad Update. This for the reasons stated above. In addition, the SQLPLUS feedback given (X amount records updated) would also be false, as it does not differ between records needing update, and records not needing updates. Not to mention unnecessary Undo creation, triggers fired, etc.

Comment: As an improvisation to the answer, I have edited my answer and included the query predicate. By the way, OP seem to accept an answer which is outside to Oracle db. Not sure why Oracle was even tagged.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70038/discussion-between-tvca-and-lalit-kumar-b).